# How to resize QEMU VNC session with noVNC web-based client

Tags: resize, qemu, novnc

The noVNC does support resize the session size from client to server with the SetDesktopSize message of the RFB protocol. But it requires the VNC server to support the 'ExtendedDesktopSize' encoding which is unfortunately not supported by QEMU.

Will QEMU support the 'ExtendedDesktopSize' encoding in the future? Is there any other approach to resize the QEMU VNC session?